# How can I make a flexbox layout (2 rows - (2 columns & 1 column) ) with a full-width visjs inside?

Tags: html, css, layout, vis.js

I am creating a layout with three boxes - two horizontally connected and one below them both. My goal is to have a layout flex so that everything is proportional and fits to the size of the screen used (no scrolling). The largest, lower box will have a canvas (visjs -should fit a 100% of the width).

The height of the left box is controlled by the content inside, and its width is a percentage of the row.

The bottom box should fill the remaining height.

All boxes together should fill the screen of the page (in other words, no scrolling option).

```
 --------------
| L% |    R    |
 --------------
|              |
|    CANVAS    |
|    vis.js    |
|              |
 --------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've been trying to solve this all day long without success. I am not going to publish my code that is trash. I hope somebody can offer a "good" answer to solve this problem and in the future if somebody needs something similar he/she can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Thank you so much for your comments. Combining the two answers proposed here I found a solution that works for my needs.

```css
html, body {
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}

header .top-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

header .top-right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  vertical-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px dashed fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <header>
    <div class="top-left"> a </div>
    <div class="top-right"> b </div>
  </header>
  <main> c </main>
</div>
```

I think, I am abusing of the use of display: flex. Anyway, at least is working now. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Use nested [flex-boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}

header .top-left {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

header .top-right {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
  flex: 1;
}

main {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.indicator {
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #666;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top-left">
    <p class="indicator">L_20%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="top-right">
    <p class="indicator">R</p>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <p class="indicator">CANVAS<br>vis.js</p>
</main>
```

Comment: It looks fantastic, I ran the code snippet and work correctly but for some reason in my angular project I cannot get the full height of the bottom box. I tried to use in "main" a style of height:100vh but now over pass the height of the body (I have a scrolling part)

Comment: You will have to check all parent elements of your real scenario and adapt the styles accordingly. Without providing a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to help. Questions seeking code help should include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a **[Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)**.
Think about opening a new question with more context.

Comment: I check your solution on (https://jsfiddle.net/) and it's working fine. The problem is when I do the same in my Angular project. For some reason is not filling the page. The left and right header are working well, but the bottom box is not filling the remaining height. As I told you, I set the height of main to 100vh and almost work correct, but add an extra space at the end (I can scroll down). By the way, thanks for your prompt response my friend!! @Daniel Sixl